# PATCH fetch json body to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, strong-parameters

I'm PATCHing a form to Rails through `fetch`, but some attributes are not handled properly on the server side.

> I'm running Rails `5.2.2` over Ruby `ruby 2.5.1p57`

When I post the data to the server, I get this `console.log` output in browser:

```
{id: 10172, weekday: 1, is_only_private: false, is_allow_forced: false, from_time: 08:00, to_time: 09:00, act_ids: [10001, 10002], customer_id: 10000, consultation_id: 10000}
```

But on the server side I can see this log on console:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"10172", "weekday"=>1, "is_only_private"=>false, "is_allow_forced"=>false, "from_time"=>"08:00", "to_time"=>"09:00", "act_ids"=>[10001, 10002], "customer_id"=>"10000", "consultation_id"=>"10000", "timetable"=>{"id"=>"10172", "weekday"=>1, "is_only_private"=>false, "is_allow_forced"=>false, "from_time"=>"08:00", "to_time"=>"09:00"}}
```

> `act_ids` disappears inside `timetable` attribute

My app it's hybrid, it's responding with HTML and JSON (even XML) in the same routes.

Question:

**Is not it solved in this version of Rails yet?**

---

**Workaround with this**

```rb
  def timetable_params
    my_params = params.require(:timetable).permit :weekday,
                                                  :is_only_private,
                                                  :is_allow_forced,
                                                  :from_time,
                                                  :to_time,
                                                  act_ids: []

    my_params[:act_ids] ||= params[:act_ids]

    my_params
  end
```

Comment: What is `request.request_parameters` for this request?

Comment: @Vasfed: {"id"=>"10172", "weekday"=>1, "is_only_private"=>false, "is_allow_forced"=>false, "from_time"=>"08:00", "to_time"=>"09:00", "act_ids"=>[10001, 10002], "customer_id"=>"10000", "consultation_id"=>"10000"}

Comment: Can you create a typo err, and verify what shows in the parameters when you submit the form? How are you declaring act_ids on your form?

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes; Typo??? Typo in fields or values?

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes, It's sended from ReactJS component. But the problem is'nt client side, it's Rails doing `magic`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you permitted it as `permit(..., :to_time, :act_ids)`, but array should be permitted via `act_ids: []`, which you already have in your `timetable_params` code

On clean application this works correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "bundler/inline"

gemfile(!!ENV['INSTALL']) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem 'rails', '5.2.2'
end

require "action_controller/railtie"

class TestApp < Rails::Application
  config.root = __dir__
  config.eager_load = false
  config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "cookie_store_key"
  secrets.secret_key_base = "secret_key_base"

  config.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  Rails.logger  = config.logger
end

TestApp.initialize!
TestApp.routes.draw{ resources :timetables, only: :update }


class TimetablesController < ActionController::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  wrap_parameters format: [:json, :xml]

  def update
    render json: timetable_params
  end

  def timetable_params
    params.require(:timetable).permit(:weekday,
                                      :is_only_private,
                                      :is_allow_forced,
                                      :from_time,
                                      :to_time,
                                      act_ids: [])
  end
end

require "minitest/autorun"
require "rack/test"

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def test_returns_success
    payload = {
      "id"=>"10172", "weekday"=>1, "is_only_private"=>false, "is_allow_forced"=>false,
      "from_time"=>"08:00", "to_time"=>"09:00",
      "act_ids"=>[10001, 10002],
      "customer_id"=>"10000", "consultation_id"=>"10000"
    }

    patch "/timetables/10172.json", payload.to_json, { 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json' }

    assert last_response.ok?
    puts "resp body: #{last_response.body}"
    resp = JSON.parse(last_response.body)

    assert_includes(resp.keys, "act_ids")
  end

  private def app
    Rails.application
  end
end
```

produces

```
Run options: --seed 62182

# Running:

I, [2019-06-14T16:04:02.967561 #44749]  INFO -- : Started PATCH "/timetables/10172.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-06-14 16:04:02 +0300
I, [2019-06-14T16:04:02.971039 #44749]  INFO -- : Processing by TimetablesController#update as JSON
I, [2019-06-14T16:04:02.971161 #44749]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10172", "weekday"=>1, "is_only_private"=>false, "is_allow_forced"=>false, "from_time"=>"08:00", "to_time"=>"09:00", "act_ids"=>[10001, 10002], "customer_id"=>"10000", "consultation_id"=>"10000", "timetable"=>{"id"=>"10172", "weekday"=>1, "is_only_private"=>false, "is_allow_forced"=>false, "from_time"=>"08:00", "to_time"=>"09:00", "act_ids"=>[10001, 10002], "customer_id"=>"10000", "consultation_id"=>"10000"}}
D, [2019-06-14T16:04:02.971850 #44749] DEBUG -- : Unpermitted parameters: :id, :customer_id, :consultation_id
I, [2019-06-14T16:04:02.972484 #44749]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms)


resp body: {"weekday":1,"is_only_private":false,"is_allow_forced":false,"from_time":"08:00","to_time":"09:00","act_ids":[10001,10002]}
.

Finished in 0.020124s, 49.6919 runs/s, 149.0757 assertions/s.
1 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```